# FL Studio on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, wine, lts, playonlinux

Can you help me run FL Studio 12 on ubuntu 16.04 lts?
Recently I have bought a copy of it. I tried running it through PlayOnLinux and Wine, but it always keeps giving me an error called "QuickFontCache.dll is missing." just before finishing instalation.
I went to the image-line forum and nothing.
I can't go to windows because my hdd is almost full and i dont want to lose my stuff. ubuntu is my main os.
Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please provide some more details and a screenshot of the error and/or paste some terminal output. Does the program otherwise run (despite continuing giving the error) or does it not even run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/FL_Studio/comments/4ucx0i/tutorial_how_to_install_fl_studio_on_linux/) reddit thread you can install FL Studio 12 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Here are the required steps from that thread:

- Download playonlinux. `sudo apt-get install playonlinux`
- Run it and make sure it launches. `playonlinux`
- Go to Tools -> Manage Wine Versions. In Wine versions (x86), install the version 1.9.15. Select the version in the left box and click ">".
- Click Install and then Install a non-listed program.
- Click through the welcome screen.
- Select "Install a program in a new virtual drive".
- Pick a name for your virtual drive (like "flstudio").
- In the next window, don't check anything and click Next.
- Select "32-bit Windows installation". Then wait a minute while your drive is being created.
- Next click Browse and look for your FL Studio installation .exe. One thing to note is that your main file system in Wine is always mapped under the disk letter Z:.
- Click through the installation. Once you reach the "Choose which features of FL Studio 12 you want to install", uncheck Desktop icons and Asio4All. Install everything in its default directories.
- In the final screen, select "FL" as your shortcut.
- Once FL Studio is installed, try to run it and make sure it launches. You will most likely not see any text and the program will not be registered.
- To fix the no text issue, select the FL in your playonlinux main window, go to Configure -> Install components and install the Microsoft Core Fonts and tahoma packages.
- To register your copy of FL Studio, go to Configure -> Wine -> Registry Editor. Then go to Registry -> Import Registry File... and navigate to where your registration key is located. Then exit the registry editor.
- Launch your FL Studio and verify that everything works (for instance, open newstuff.flp).
- Open audio settings and set your sound driver to FL Studio ASIO.

For more info regarding the known issues and errors please refer to the thread.

And if that is not working for you , the most probable solution will be either to use a windows virtual machine or dual boot ubuntu with windows , if you are not interested in going the either way , the best possible solution will be a combination of [lmms](https://lmms.io/) and [audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/).

Comment: fl 12 crashes right on launch. but fl 11.1.1 works fine ty :)

Comment: i can work with that :D

Comment: Go on , linux all the way!